# Error in SUMO dlr

Tags: terminal

```
map % -n map.net.xml --osm-files map.osm --type-file typemap.xml -o map.poly.xml
zsh: command not found: -n
```

Any idea on how to solve this error?

Comment: Is this command from some instructions you are following? Can you add a link to those, and/or describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish here and which command you want to run?

Answer (score 1):

You haven’t provided a command, only options to a command.

For example, `ls -l` runs `ls` with the option `-l`. Just `-l` on its own has no meaning.

You’ve tried to run `-n …`, so there’s no command given.

Comment: -n is used for net file